# How is $\frac{1 * 3 \dots (2N+1)}{2^{N+1}} = \frac{(2N+2)!}{2^{2N+2}(N+1)!}$

Tags: real-analysis

$\frac{1 * 3 \dots (2N+1)}{2^{N+1}} = \frac{(2N+2)!}{2^{2N+2}(N+1)!}$

but I'm having a hard time seeing it... Starting with the LHS if we try to match the denominators then we can do this by multiply by $2^{N+1}(N+1)!$

so $\frac{1 * 3 \dots (2N+1)}{2^{N+1}}*\frac{2^{N+1}(N+1)!}{2^{N+1}(N+1)!} = \frac{\text{something}}{2^{2N+2}(N+1)!}$

but I don't see how the numerators ("something") multiplies to $(2N+2)!$

I'm looking at part (a) [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781493927111-understanding-analysis-2nd-edition/205/exercises/10/) if that matters.

Comment: The numerator is $$(2N+1)!!=\frac{(2N+2)!}{(2N+2)!!}=\frac{(2N+2)!}{2^{N+1}(N+1)!}$$where$$(2N+2)!!=(2N+2)\cdot(2N)\cdots2$$

Comment: Do you know $1\times2\times3\times4\times\dots\times2N\times(2N+1)=1\times3\times\dots\times(2N+1)\times2\times4\times\dots\times2N=1\times3\times\dots\times(2N+1)\times2^N\times1\times2\times\dots\times N=1\times3\times\dots\times(2N+1)\times2^N\times N!?$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that 
$$2^{N+1}(N+1)!=2^{N+1}(1*2*\cdots(N+1))\\=2*2^2*\cdots*(2N+2)$$
Thus
$$1*3*\cdots*(2N+1)*2^{N+1}(N+1)!=1*3*\cdots*(2N+1)*2*2^2*\cdots*(2N+2)\\=(2N+2)!$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2N+1)}{2^{N+1}} 
&= \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{N+1} (2k-1)}{2^{N+1}} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{N+1} (2k-1) \prod_{k=1}^{N+1} (2k)}{2^{N+1}\prod_{k=1}^{N+1} (2k)} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2N+2} k}{2^{N+1} 2^{N+1}\prod_{k=1}^{N+1} k} \\
&= \frac{(2N+2)!}{2^{2N+2}(N+1)!}\\
\end{align}